# Using method from one class in another?

Tags: python, pygame

I am attempting to create two sprites for my game, one being `Player1` and the other `Player2`, therefore they will have very similar attributes. I am trying to work out how I can use all the methods I have for my `Player1` class with my `Player2` class.

```
class Player2(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self):
      Player1.__init__(self)
      self.rect.x = 400
      self.walkImages = ["p2 walk/Run (1).png", "p2 walk/Run (2).png", "p2 walk/Run (3).png", "p2 walk/Run (4).png", "p2 walk/Run (5).png", "p2 walk/Run (6).png", "p2 walk/Run (7).png",
                         "p2 walk/Run (8).png"]

      self.idleImages = ["p2 idle/Idle (1).png", "p2 idle/Idle (2).png", "p2 idle/Idle (3).png", "p2 idle/Idle (4).png", "p2 idle/Idle (5).png", "p2 idle/Idle (6).png", "p2 idle/Idle (7).png",
                         "p2 idle/Idle (8).png", "p2 idle/Idle (9).png", "p2 idle/Idle (10).png"]

  def update(Player1, blocksGroup):
      pass
```

When creating my `Player2` class, I inherit from `Player1`. However, with my update method, it theoretically would be identical to `Player1`s. How would I go about using `Player1`'s method to update?

Here is the update method for `Player1`:

```
  def update(self, blocksGroup):
    self.gravity()

    if self.velx == 0:
        self.walkFrame = 1
        self.idleFrame += 1
        if self.idleFrame == 42:
            self.idleFrame = 0

        if self.idleFrame % 3 == 0:
            self.image = pygame.image.load(self.idleImages[self.idleFrame // 3])
            if self.direction == "left":
                self.image = pg.transform.flip(self.image, True, False)


    #Block collision

    self.rect.x += self.velx
    block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, blocksGroup, False)
    for block in block_hit_list:
        if self.velx > 0:
            self.rect.right = block.rect.left
        elif self.velx < 0:
            self.rect.left = block.rect.right

    self.rect.y += self.vely
    block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, blocksGroup, False)
    for block in block_hit_list:
        if self.vely > 0:
            self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
            self.jumps = 2
        elif self.vely < 0:
            self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom
```

Comment: While you say that `Player2` "inherit[s] from `Player1`", the code you've shown doesn't match. Perhaps you want `class Player2(Player1)`? A more natural way to solve the problem may be to move the common parts to a base class that both players can inherit from.

Comment: It sounds to me that you actually just want two different instances of the same class, one with the images for player 1 and the other with the images for player 2. Is that assumption correct? BTW, don't load the images from your hard disk in the update method. Do that in the global scope or another module and refer to them in the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't really said how the `Player1` and `Player2` classes are *different*, but assuming you have a good reason I would suggested creating a base class called `PlayerBase` and using that as the base class for these two other classes.

This will make it very clear they share behavior and only differences will need to be implemented in the methods of each subclass.

The reason I said "assuming you have a good reason" for having two classes, is because if the only difference between them is what data they contain, for example, you don't need to have two classes to do that—instead just define the `__init__()` method of a (single) class so it accepts arguments that provide this data and then store it if necessary as class instance data via the `self` argument which is passed by default to all regular methods.

There's a section titled  [**Objects and classes**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming#Objects_and_classes) in Wikipedia's article on [Object-oriented Programming (OOP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) which discusses the difference between the two which might provide you more insight into when you should use one or the other to do things.

Comment: Your first sentence suggests another possible solution, that there may actually need to be two `PlayerX` classes, and that they could both be instances of the same class (with whatever differences they have being due to the different arguments they were passed).

Comment: @Blckknght: That's exactly why I hedged what I said a bit and wrote  "assuming you have good reason" (for having two separate classes). I think it's a fairly common mistake for folks to think they need a separate class whenever something that could be handled by simply storing different attribute values within a single class (and using them to control instances's behavior).

Comment: Considering there are only a few pieces of data I am changing such as the images and starting positions, I have done what you suggested and used one class with different data passed in. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If `Player2` inherits from `Player1` and the `update` method is exactly the same, then you can simply not define `update` for `Player2`.

In that case, when `update` is called by a `Player2` object, it will use the inherited definition from `Player1` and `self` will refer to the `Player2` instance.